# pprint: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, dictionary, pprint

This is driving me crazy. I'm trying to `pprint` a `dict` with an **é** char, and it throws me out.

I'm using Python 3:

```
    from pprint import pprint
    knights = {'gallahad': 'the pure', 'robin': 'the bravé'}
    pprint (knights)
```

Error:

```
File "/data/prod_envs/pythons/python36/lib/python3.6/pprint.py", line 176, in _format
stream.write(rep)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 43: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I read up on the Python ASCII doc, but there does not seem a quick way to solve this, other than taking the dict apart, and rewriting the offending value to an ASCII value via `.encode`, and then re-assembling the dict again

Is there any way I can get this to print without taking the dict apart?

Comment: How are you running that script? What does `sys.stdout.encoding` tell you?

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Hi, no, I'm on a Linux box

Answer (score 7):

This is unrelated to `pprint`: the module only *formats* the string into another string and then passes the formatted string to the underlying stream. So your error occurs when the `é` character (U+00E9) is written to stdout.

Now it really depends on the underlying OS and the configuration of the Python interpreter. In Linux or other Unix-like systems, you could try to declare a UTF-8 or Latin1 charset in your terminal session by setting the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING` before starting Python:

```
$ export PYTHONIOENCODING=Latin1
$ python
```

(or use `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` depending on the actual encoding of your terminal or terminal window).

Comment: ok, just tried this on my machine :`echo "hello worldé"` and that's working. So if it's OS config,  i would expect that printing this to stdout would also raise an error.  But it does not ....

Comment: Just note this variable overrides `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` all at once. Python3 [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING)

Answer (score 0):

Standard input and output are file objects in Python.  [The Python 3 documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) that, when these objects are created, if `encoding` is left unspecified then `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to fetch the locale's preferred encoding.

Your system should have been set up with one or more "locales" when GNU/Linux was installed (I'm guessing from your paths that you are using some version of GNU/Linux).  On a "sensible" setup, the default locale should allow UTF-8.  But if you only did a "minimal" installation (for example as part of setting up a container), or something like that, then it is possible that the system has set locale to `"C"` (the ultimate fallback locale), which does not support UTF-8.

Just because your *terminal* can accept UTF-8 (as demonstrated by using `echo` with a UTF-8 string), does not mean *Python knows* that UTF-8 is acceptable.  If Python sees the locale set to `"C"` then it will assume only ASCII is allowed unless told otherwise.

You can check the current locale by typing `locale` at the shell prompt, and change it by setting the `LC_ALL` environment variable.  But before changing it you must check with `locale -a` to see which locales are available on your system, otherwise your change may not be effective and you may get the `"C"` locale anyway.  If your system has not been set up with the locale you want, you can add it if you have root access: most GNU/Linux distributions provide options to do this when you (re)configure a package called `locales`, so for example on Debian/Ubuntu-based distros, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` should show you the options.

But sometimes you will be in the awkward position of having to write a Python script to run on a system that has *not* been set up with decent locales and there's *nothing* you can do about it because you don't have root and the sysadmin insists on giving you the absolute minimum.  *Then* what do we do?

Well there are options within Python itself.  You could run `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` before running Python, to tell Python to use that encoding no matter what the locale says.  Or you could give `pprint` a `stream=` parameter, set to a stream that you've opened yourself using `open()` with an `encoding="utf-8"` parameter (although this is no good if you want to use `sys.stdout` or `os.popen` instead of a file).  Or you could upgrade to Python 3.7 and use `sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')` (but this won't work in the Python 3.6 mentioned in the original question).

Or, you could `import codecs` and do `w=codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.buffer)` and then pass `stream=w` to your `pprint`:

```
from pprint import pprint
import sys, codecs
w=codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.buffer)
d = {"testing": "这是个考验"}
pprint (d, stream=w)
```